# How to actorSelection Remote Akka Actor on another host

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I want to send message to an akka actor on another host.
How should I put in actor path?
In example here's `val remoteActor = akka.tcp://application@localhost:6001/user/receiver` configuration when I put it on same host.
But I want to deploy this actor on another host. I have change localhost with remote hostname and public IP, but still cannot create instantiation,
`val actorRemote  = context.actorSelection(remoteActor)`

Any helps ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With `context.actorSelection` you don't create actors, but you can send messages to an actor identified by it's address. To remotely deploy an actor you should do [this way](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/remoting.html#Programmatic_Remote_Deployment):

```
import akka.actor.{ Props, Deploy, Address, AddressFromURIString }
import akka.remote.RemoteScope

val address = AddressFromURIString("akka.tcp://sys@host:1234")
val ref = system.actorOf(Props[SampleActor].
  withDeploy(Deploy(scope = RemoteScope(address))))
```